# A WPF datagrid using Entity Framework won't let you edit

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

Long time C# / Winforms guy now crossing the divide to Entity Framework and WPF.
I've got a datagrid that has no columns and the code that I run is :

```
using (var some = new BloggingContext())
{
    var query = (from g in some.SomeTables
                 select new { g.dtTrans, g.Id, g.nNum, g.SumString }).ToList();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = query;               
}
```

The datagrid is correct, but it won't enable an edit and my code behind has `IsReadOnly = False`.

Is there some trick to enable editing or am I way off base?

My class is:

```
public class SomeTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime dtTrans { get; set; }
    public string SumString { get; set; }
    public decimal nNum { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SomeTable> SomeTables { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're using an anonymous type as the items source, you have to bind it to a real collection (An ObservableCollection for example)

Comment: How to do this? What is needed to change on that line: dataGrid.ItemsSource = query

Comment: Change query `var query = (from g in some.SomeTables
                 select new SomeTable { dtTrans = g.dtTrans, Id =g.Id, nNum = g.nNum, SumString = g.SumString }).ToList();`

Comment: "The entity or complex type 'WPFEf.SomeTable' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."